# Pinterest customize image share list

Tags: image, customization, social-networking, pinterest

I'm trying to add a custom pinterest link to my website.

[widget builder](http://business.pinterest.com/widget-builder/#do_pin_it_button)

```
<a href="javascript:void((function()%7Bvar%20e=document.createElement(&apos;script&apos;);e.setAttribute(&apos;type&apos;,&apos;text/javascript&apos;);e.setAttribute(&apos;charset&apos;,&apos;UTF-8&apos;);e.setAttribute(&apos;src&apos;,&apos;http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinmarklet.js?r=&apos;+Math.random()*99999999);document.body.appendChild(e)%7D)());">
```

[Someone's jsfiddle custom link](http://jsfiddle.net/hUAh8/1/)

How can I customize the images I can share? When the popup appears, there are several irrelevant images (assets, icons, etc). How can I select part of them.

I've looked at [this example](https://github.com/mustaine/Pinmarklet) but it does not seem right, because it throws exceptions and it lacks documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a URL variable (media) for specifying a specific image. The answer is in [the official documentation](https://developers.pinterest.com/pin_it/).